# vscode typescript intellisense for exported modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

IntelliSense works as expected in my main project file where I imported a third-party library to my project;

Example: I'm using a library "Directus," however, when exporting the class and importing in another file in my project, IntelliSense stops working.

```
import { Directus } from '@directus/sdk';

export class Editor {
    public async directus(): Promise<any> {
        let directus = new Directus("http://localhost:8055/");
        await directus.auth.login({
          email: "email@admin",
          password: "password",
        });
        return directus
    }
}
```

[image]

When importing the class in another file test.ts (IntelliSense stops working)

I'm not sure if this is a vscode issue or typescript configuration problem.

[image]

```
import { Editor } from ".";
let test = new Editor();
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the actual source text.

Comment: I have updated the post to include a code sample, I really just wanted to describe what the issue was

Comment: The code you included in your updated question matches my previous expectation of what it would look like. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193754/438273).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a property on an async method. Instead use this syntax:

```ts
const test = new Editor(); // create object instance
const directus = await test.directus(); // call method returning promise and await its value
directus.propertyName // access a property on the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jsejcksn for pointing out that I needed to `await` for the method.

I have also needed to return the correct type, instead of using  `any` returning `TypeMap`

```
import { Directus, TypeMap } from '@directus/sdk';

export class Editor {
    public async directus(): Promise<Directus<TypeMap>> {
        let directus = new Directus("http://localhost:8055/");
        await directus.auth.login({
          email: "email@admin",
          password: "password",
        });
        return directus
    }
}
```

Now IntelliSense works as expected.

[image]